# Should an explicit answer be given to a time sensitive question or is linking to a constantly updated resource more helpful?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes an answer is only correct for a short period of time. Is it better to provide a link to a resource that provides an up-to-date answer? It seems that for posterity, an answer that will be correct later as well as immediately is preferable.

## Example

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805635/browser-for-css-shaders/), posted a year ago, asks which browsers support CSS Shaders. The information in all the answers is/was no longer current.

[I responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805635/browser-for-css-shaders/21165470#21165470) with a link to CanIUse.com which provides current feature compatibility tables for all the popular browsers but I wasn't sure if I should have also included an explicit answer that was the correct at the time of answering.

I understand that providing a clear answer to the question is generally the goal but it seems counter-productive if it's going to change.

Comment: Ah, where is good old "too localized" when you need it.

Comment: My question? Or questions that have expiring answers?

Comment: The question you've linked. It's inherently problematic. The answer you've given is as good as it gets. Yet it's bad at the same time. There's no winning here.

Comment: @Bart I see the question as one that seeks an external tool, library... etc. So I've voted to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Links to external sites are even more problematic, because many of them doesn't exist anymore, and the answers are still there. Better would be to cite the appropriate part and provide link as back-reference.

However, the problem is in question and not in answer. This is namely the list question (what y-s have property x). If it would be formulated in other way:

> Does Firefox 142 or Chrome 666 support CSS Shaders?

there would be no problem now. The answer would be still actual, even if because of new version released it would be niche.

Comment: Correct spot - the question is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I wasn't sure if I should have also included an explicit answer that was the correct at the time of answering.

Yes, you should have. That way if the linked service is down, your answer still retains as much value as possible.

On the other hand, questions that can only have short-time, constantly invalidating answers are not that good. They borderline shopping questions and it is usually better to answer with instructions about how to find out, what are standards etc, than a simple yes/no. In your specific case, you did it with your link.

Comment: What about the problem that including a temporary answer creates? If someone adds a new answer later with current information, it might not get voted up/selected as correct. Should that matter or is it just important to have the answer on the page somewhere?

Comment: @2xj if answer is deleted after more than 30 days, answerer keeps reputation earned. This is exactly to allow deletion of outdated answers if question's nature or ever-evolving nature of IT world will render it outdated. And we have edit feature, editing more recent data from the linked page is always a valid thing to do, as it does not change the nature of answer edited at all, just it's point in time.

Comment: Ah, nice. I didn't know that. Thank you.